# c# asp.net check if column in database contains string

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my database, the column is stored as 'Here is jurong', I want to read out the database row if the column contains the word jurong.
I tried using like but it cant work

Here is the code, please help

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Thread WHERE (Delete_Status='No') AND (Thread_Location = '" + searchTB.Text + "' OR Thread_Title = '" + searchTB.Text + "' OR Thread_Description LIKE '%' + @Thread_Description + '%') ORDER BY ThreadID DESC ", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Thread_Description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = searchTB.Text;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            reptater.DataSource = ds;
            reptater.DataBind();
```

Comment: Can you tell me which column stored as jurong word? Location ?,Thread_Title?,Thread_Description?

Comment: @anonymous, Code seems to be working fine. You must have problem at other places in code.

Answer (score 0):

Does that SQL statement return rows when you run it in the database? Also, I'd be careful of SQL injection attacks when passing values not through parameters.

Should your 'reptater' bind to a DataTable rather than a DataSet?

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Thread WHERE (Delete_Status='No') AND (Thread_Location = @SearchTxt OR Thread_Title = @SearchTxt OR Thread_Description LIKE '%' + @SearchTxt + '%') ORDER BY ThreadID DESC ", con);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchTxt", SqlDbType.VarChar);
cmd.Parameters["@SearchTxt"].Value = searchTB.Text;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
reptater.DataSource = ds; //ds.Tables[0]; ?
reptater.DataBind();
```